# Actionscript 3 - setting the quality of individual movieclips

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a way to do this?

I have a bunch of photos scrolling left and right and I need to reduce the jerkiness of the scrolling motion somehow (so it works well on slower machines). Is there another way to do this via AS3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the quality separately from the stage quality. What you can do is set the smoothing of the Bitmaps you are using via BitmapData.

See more about it here:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/

Rob